# Different de-Broglie wavelength due to different reference frames

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, wave-particle-duality

Suppose that an electron moves in the $+x$ direction with some velocity $v$. If there are two observers $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ moves with a velocity $v_1$ in the $+x$ direction and $B$ is at rest with respect to origin, will $A$ and $B$ observe different values of de Broglie’s wavelength of that electron?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I couldn't quite follow A,B,+v, and the origin, but it doesn't matter.
Any observer sees the electron moving with some velocity $\vec v$. That motion can be captured in a 4-velocity:

$$ u^{\mu}= (\gamma c, \gamma \vec v) $$

which transform to other frames moving at $\vec \beta$ via:

$$ u'^{\mu}=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu }(\vec{\beta})u^{\nu}$$

where $\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu }(\vec{\beta})$ is the Lorentz transformation.

The electron's energy ($E$) and momentum ($\vec v$) form the 4-momentum:

$$ p^{\mu} = (E/c, \vec p)=(\gamma mc,\gamma m \vec v) = mu^{\mu} $$

which also transform via $\Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \nu }(\vec{\beta})$.

The relativistic form of the de Broglie relations is:

$$ p^{\mu} = \hbar k^{\mu} $$

where:

$$ k^{\mu} = (\omega/c, \vec k) $$

is the 4-wave vector.

Note that it always easier to derive coordinate-free relations with the wave-vector than with the wavelength, though the wavelength is more intuitive when 1st studying waves. For a wave with wavelength $\lambda$ traveling in the direction $\hat n$, the wave vector is:

$$ \vec k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} \hat n$$

Moreover, it puts the time component $k^0=\omega/c$ on equally footing with the space component $k^j=n^j\times 2\pi/\lambda$. The former (latter) is the rate oscillation in time (space). Since boosts mix time and space, $k^{\mu}$ captures those effects on $\omega$ and $\vec k$ (and hence, $\lambda$).

If $\beta$ is co-linear with $\vec v$ (along $\hat z$), we can take the standard energy and momentum transformations:

$$ p' = \gamma(p-\frac{E\beta}{c}) $$
$$ E' = \gamma(E-\beta cp) $$

and insert the de Broglie relations:

$$ \hbar k' = \gamma(\hbar k-\frac{\hbar\omega\beta}{c}) $$
$$ \hbar\omega' = \gamma(\hbar\omega-\beta c\hbar k) $$

or in terms of wavelength (and period, $T$, for reciprocity):

$$ \frac{2\pi}{\lambda'} = \gamma(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}-\frac{\frac{2\pi}T\beta}{c}) $$
$$ \frac{2\pi}{T'}  = \gamma(\frac{2\pi}T-\beta c\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}) $$

Those simplify to:

$$ \lambda'=\frac 1{\gamma}\frac{\lambda cT}{cT-\lambda\beta}$$

$$ T'=\frac 1{\gamma}\frac{\lambda T}{\lambda-\beta cT}$$

Finally, in the limit $m\rightarrow 0$, and $v\rightarrow c$, you have $cT = \lambda$, along with $\gamma =1/\sqrt{(1+\beta)(1-\beta)}$:

$$\lambda' = \lambda \sqrt{\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}} $$

$$T' = T \sqrt{\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}} $$

which are the standard formulae for the relativistic Doppler shift.

Answer (score 0):

Under a Galilean boost transformation to a frame moving at veclocity $U$ the Schroedinger wavefunction transforms to
$$
\psi(x,t)\mapsto e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}i(mUx - \frac 12 mU^2t) } \psi(x-Ut,t),
$$
so yes both the wavelength and frequecy are  changed.